# Write to csv column wise from dataframe based on number of columns generated

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the below data:

```
sv_m1   rev     ioip    are
0       15.31   40      NJ
0       64.9    0       CX
0       18.36   20      FP
0       62.85   0       CX
0       10.31   20      NJ
0       12.84   10      CX
0       69.95   0       FP
0       32.81   20      BS
```

I have the above data in a csv from which I am reading in a single column at a time and doing some processing.
Then I want to write to a csv, each column at a time.
So sv_m1 will be written first, then rev and ioip. Since are is a categorical variable, it will be converted to dummies and 4 columns will be written to 
the csv at once.
As can be understood, the number of columns during each write might vary based on whether it is a numeric or categorical variable.

Below is my code:

```
for column in cols_list:   
        df_column = pd.read_csv('df_sample.csv', usecols=[column])
        #### Data processing##########
        if (attribute_dict[column] == 'CAT'): # attribute_dict contains mapping of column name and type                    
            df_target = pd.get_dummies(df_column[column], dummy_na=True, prefix=column)
            for target_column in list(df_target.columns):
                df_final[target_column] = df_target[[target_column]]

        else (attribute_dict[column] == 'NUM'):
            df_target = df_column
            df_target.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
            df_final[column] = df_target

        # Write into csv for each column.
        with open('df_final.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            /* Not sure what to do here */
```

Can someone please guide me regarding this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any reason why you can't write the entire file at once?

Comment: what do you expect the output file to contain?

Comment: csv-files are not written column wise, that's a fact to accept. you should prepare your dataset, which you want to write out and write it as soon as it's complete.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko.. It is a large dataframe if I use all the columns and hogs up a lot of memory. So objective is to take a column, process it, write it and move on to the next column